# CString += operator performance issues

Tags: c++, performance, mfc, cstring

I am working on an older MFC/C++ project that parses large text files using MFC's [CString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300688%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) class to handle strings. I noticed that during the parsing process there's a lot of adding of small parts to an overall large CString object as such:

```
//'strContainer' = CString
//'tag' = CString of a much smaller size
strContainer += L"<" + tag + L">";
```

The operator above seems to be slowing the overall performance of CString when `strContainer` variable reaches a certain larger size. I'm supposing that such happens because of the often re-allocation of memory done by the `+=` operator.

So I was curious, is there any way to improve this?

PS1. I do not know the size of the result string up front to pre-allocate it.

PS2. I have to stick with CString due to complexity of the project itself. (Or, I can't switch to Boost or other newer implementations.)

Comment: Actually, the `+=` is probably the fast part.  The performance issue is probably the `+` of the temporaries.  As such, do `+=` three times and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @MooingDuck: The issue with measuring this performance is that by itself a single operator would not be something that a human can notice. It's when I run several thousands of them in the parsing method, that's when it becomes visible. In either case, I'm positive that it's one of the `CString` operators that does memory re-allocation. I conclude it because its performance decreases exponentially with the size of `CString` variable.

Comment: Even if you can't preallocate an optimal amount, you could still preallocate enough to cover a majority of your cases. Memory is probably a lot less of a concern than when the program was first written.

Comment: Is this code compiled with optimisation (not debug mode?). I have written code that deals with seriously large strings (admittedly not CString, but I doubt it is THAT inefficient). In debug builds, it's almost certainly horribly slow because of all sorts of extra checking.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Can you show how you'd suggest to pre-allocate it? I guess I can do it progressively in the flow of the parsing process...

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Yes, debug build is way slower than the release, but there's still a large performance hit in the release build as well.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Release builds still do extra debug checking if Visual Studio started the program for you.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I just found `Preallocate` method too. Thanks. Although, I'm not sure how exactly I am supposed to use it. Will need to research a little bit deeper into it.

Comment: @c00000fd: Just call `Preallocate` before you start appending, and give it a number that's big enough for 95% of your data.  Super easy.  (The other 5% it will reallocate like it did before, but usually only once, not 10 times)

Comment: @MooingDuck: Thanks. let me try it...

Comment: I usually use `CString::Format("%s%s%s%s");` for such things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `std::string`, `+=` is usually quite fast as it can just copy bytes into already allocated buffers.  Usually, the `L"<" + tag + L">";` will require three or more memory allocations, which are completely unnecessary, if you simply replace that line of code with three `+=`.  Additionally, allocations are *REALLY REALLY SLOW* if you have Visual Studio start the program for you, even release builds.  Run your program manually without Visual Studio, and see if that solves your performance problems.

I dug into the MFC source to very this.  (And dug and dug and dug...) and found that `ATL::CSimpleStringT::PrepareWrite2(int nLength)` will grow exponentially (1.5x bigger each allocation, completely normal, `std::string` is the same, except...
If the MFC string is over 1G, it only adds 1M each allocation after that.

So there's two conditions:
If `strContainer` is over 1G, you should manually reserve memory (`Preallocate` a large number of bytes.  It doesn't have to be exact, or even greater than the real number.).
Otherwise, simply replace the `+` with `+=`.

Comment: Good find. Thanks. Although the string that I'm working with is about 50 MB in size. Way less than 1GB that you suggest. And I'm running it on a fast Windows 8 machine with Intel's i7 CPU and 16GB of RAM.

Comment: In that case, the first option.  Replace `+` with `+=`, and test with Visual Studio not attached.

Comment: Hmm ... OK. Although it gives me shivers even to think about changing the existing parsing logic. It'd be nice if I could solve it with pre-allocation first...

Comment: @c00000fd: try preallocation first, see if that's an easy fix.  Good luck!

Comment: The easiest way to use Preallocation in CString is GetBuffer with the given length. As Long as you don't midify the buffer a ReleaseBuffer isn't needed. Also using three times += instead of the temporary CString is way fatser when the buffer is preallocated.

Comment: @xMRi: I don't immediately see how `strContainer.GetBuffer(30)` is easier or more intuitive than `strContainer.Preallocate(30)`, but you're right, that until I wrote this answer, that was the way I'd known as well